# Why are commits to 7.x-master not included in latest versions of CiviCRM?

Tags: upgrade

I had two pull requests committed to 7.x-master on GitHub over the past year.

When I view the two files that were changed by my pull requests, the changes are present in the master branch.

They do not appear to be included in latest download and I end up having to manually add them.

I was under the assumption that commits to master would be included in future releases.  Is that not the case?

Comment: My understanding of the branching on github is that the master branch is the next major release. If you want your commit to be at the next minor release. e.g. 4.6.10 then you have to commit it to the 4.6.x branch. In my understanding there is no 7.x-master branch of CiviCRM. See also http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Contributing+to+CiviCRM+using+GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Github is used for the code collaboration, co-ordination of which issues are fixed in which release is done on over [CiviCRM's JIRA install](https://issues.civicrm.org).

In order to better ensure your PR was included in the next `4.6.x`, you could open an issue there and tag with appropriate versions (eg `4.6.10` for fix version), then reference the JIRA ticket in the Github PR.